# RSS "recent questions" feed includes not-recent questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, rss

Over the last few days, the [primary "recent questions" RSS feed](http://feed://scifi.stackexchange.com/feeds) (possibly also other ones) has included questions that are in no way recent.

For example, [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4558/pure-versus-hybrid-daleks) was last edited Jul 14 at 11:58 (and asked Jul 14 at 8:18), but the RSS feed lists it with an updated timestamp of 2011-09-05T23:06:50Z.

```
<entry>
    <id>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4558</id>
    <re:rank scheme="http://scifi.stackexchange.com">6</re:rank>
    <title type="text">&quot;Pure&quot; versus &quot;Hybrid&quot; Daleks</title>
    <category scheme="https://scifi.stackexchange.com/feeds/tags" term="doctor-who"/>
    <author>
        <name>gunbuster363</name>
        <uri>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1801</uri>
    </author>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4558/pure-versus-hybrid-daleks" />
    <published>2011-07-14T08:18:13Z</published>
    <updated>2011-09-05T23:06:50Z</updated>
    <summary type="html">
    [...]
    </summary>
</entry>
```

There is an *answer* that is recent.  However, the "recent questions" feed has previously meant "recently asked or edited" and not "recently asked, edited, or answered".  If this is a 'feature' change, then (a) the name is increasingly inaccurate (how does adding an answer make a *question* "recent"? Even editing is a stretch), and (b) this is significantly less useful, because it means this is no longer an efficient method of reading all questions posted to the site, because the number of old questions in the feed will overwhelm the new questions (even with our little beta site, answers outnumber questions).

I've observed this behaviour on a number of other SE sites as well, so this is not scifi.se specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one time change by design; in order to fix the "editing the title spawns a new RSS entry" bug we changed the `<id>` field to not include the title.

[Prevent title edits to spawn a new RSS post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18051/prevent-title-edits-to-spawn-a-new-rss-post)

Comment: The good old to-fix-this-we-make-it-worse-first :)  So I presume this means that any activity on any question will make it appear new, but only once per question?

Comment: @TonyMeyer - as someone who recently started using Feed Notifyer, I can confirm that yes, that's **exactly** what happens now. Any change to ANY question (including its answers) will push the question to feed front.